TypeError: Transformer._load_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'add_pooling_layer'
I got this error when i was using snowflake artic embedding model with langchain.TypeError: Transformer._load_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'add_pooling_layer'
I tried to use the snowflake artic embedding model

Broad guess but might be related to pytorch version and/or other package versions used for training a model vs inference or just some mismatch in packages in general.... not familiar with snowflake really but this feels like a familiar error from messing with LLMs.  Maybe show what you have for output from import torch; print(torch.__version__)
